# how get FRUFS loadings in python?

Tags: feature-selection

I need loading Feature Relevance based Unsupervised Feature Selection (FRUFS)

I use the code L = model_frufs.loadings_ but it does not deliver the loadings

```
    from FRUFS import FRUFS
    model_frufs = FRUFS(
        model_r=lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=42, device="gpu"),
        k=0.90)
    
    model_frufs.fit(X)
    X_pruned = model_frufs.transform(X)
    L = model_frufs.loadings_
```